# MXML versus Actionscript for flexibility

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I am developing an app which allows the user to customise every component such as button line colour, text colour etc.  Clearly I need a lot of flexibility in these components to ensure detailed customisation.

I am deciding whether to use MXML or AS for my view part of the components, I am aware AS is lighter on memory but harder to write, but am unsure on whether MXML is flexible enough for my requirements?

Comment: You probably want to use both. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why no both? I am not expert in particular, but I've worked with Flex 2 quite a while ago. Why cant you use both? MXML is better for creating UI since it's just templating / tags - while for doing some logic in the background, AS would be better in programming sense.

It's like you create your website with HTML (ie. MXML), and then in the background you support it with JS to do "richer" stuff (ie. AS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tsOverflow.  Let me rephrase to try to be clearer.  I am trying to understand whether to use MXML or AS for the UI part of the app specifically, I don't know yet whether MXML will suffice for pure flexibility?

Comment: for the "UI part" meant laying out widgets, placing buttons, etc right?  - Like I mentioned before doing all those in MXML would be much easier, straight forward and readable. But in terms of "flexibility" it really depends how much do you really  need? Obviously doing things all in AS would give you more functionality, but I would think it would be quite horrible to write and maintain is everything done in AS.

Comment: I decided to go for AS in the end due to the flexibility required, plus it needed to read from an XML.